# How can be information criteria used with non-independent samples?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, model-selection, information-criteria

I'm puzzled by the following. Many, if not all, of the Information Criteria (AIC, WAIC, LOOIC, PSIS, ...) rely on the independence of the samples -- that we can remove a part, that one point is independent of the others which is important for the point-wise calculation. This, if I understand it correctly, poses a problem with trial dependent fits, eg. time series or behavioural data. However, the hierarchical Bayesian models as stated in [this tutorial, point 4)](https://ccs-lab.github.io/hBayesDM/articles/getting_started.html) clearly say to and use these criteria to compare between models. How is that possible? I understand that you/they can compute it but it does not represent the reality, it is wrong. And what is the alternative to actually be able to deal with trial dependent models, what to use to compare them? The other examples are for example from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.04544.pdf) (Vehtari 2016) example 4.4 or the general implementations of Reinforcement Learning models in [here](https://github.com/CCS-Lab/hBayesDM/tree/master/commons/stan_files).

EDIT/Note:
I understand that one way of going around is to use several subjects (groups of observations) and then do the comparison on their level treating them as independent samples and then compare with no problems. But that was not my main problem :).